# Why does trying to access element in hash table change the insertion behaviour

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I check to see if the element is already in the hash table and that changes the output
Can someone please explain why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        char c = 'a';
        unordered_map<char,int> myhashmap;
        cout << myhashmap[c] << endl;       // <<--- This line
        myhashmap.insert({c,1});
        cout << myhashmap[c] << endl;
        cout << endl;
}
```

The output is

```
0
0
```

But if I remove the line which is marked, then the output is

```
1
```

At first I thought, it could be because checking for a key might insert it with value zero and when I actually insert it, that will be a collision. So I checked how unordered_map handles collision. Apparently it puts it in buckets. So I did this next to see if my doubt is right. All I am doing is printing all the buckets and their sizes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char c = 'a';
    unordered_map<char,int> myhashmap;

    for (unsigned i=0; i<myhashmap.bucket_count(); ++i) {
        std::cout << "bucket #" << i << " has " << myhashmap.bucket_size(i) << " elements.\n";
  }
  cout << endl;
  cout << myhashmap[c] << endl;             // Line 1 - check if the key is present
  cout << endl;

  for (unsigned i=0; i<myhashmap.bucket_count(); ++i) {
        std::cout << "bucket #" << i << " has " << myhashmap.bucket_size(i) << " elements.\n";
  }

  cout << endl;
  myhashmap.insert({c,1});                  // Line 2 - Insert into hashTable
  cout << myhashmap[c] << endl;
  cout << endl;

  for (unsigned i=0; i<myhashmap.bucket_count(); ++i) {
        std::cout << "bucket #" << i << " has " << myhashmap.bucket_size(i) << " elements.\n";
  }
}
```

Alas, my hypothesis is wrong. Initially sizes of all the buckets were zero. When I check for the key (Line 1), size of one of the buckets became 1. But even after the insertion (Line 2), the size of bucket remains 1, but the output is 0 instead of 1. I must have misunderstood something very basic with hash tables. I would appreciate it if someone could explain what I am doing wrong

Thanks

Comment: `operator[]` adds the key (with default value) if it's not there yet. `insert()` doesn't do anything if the key already exists; in particular, it doesn't replace the value associated with that key. You confuse two meanings of the word "collision" - inserting the exact same key a second time, and inserting a distinct key that just happens to have the same hash. "Put in buckets" part applies to the second meaning; it's an implementation detail irrelevant to the issue at hand.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That's the answer, post it as such so we can upvote it.

Comment: [RTFM vol 1](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at), [RTFM vol 2](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant, I said that to myself after looking at Igor's answer and I went to the pages to read properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At first I thought, it could be because checking for a key might insert it with value zero

That is precisely what is going on. You are not checking for it correctly. Here is how to see what gets inserted when you do `myhashmap[c]`:

```
char c = 'a';
unordered_map<char,int> myhashmap;
cout << "Size before: " << myhashmap.size() << endl;
cout << myhashmap[c] << endl;
cout << "Size after: " << myhashmap.size() << endl;\
auto iter = myhashmap.find(c);
cout << "iter is valid: " << (iter != myhashmap.end()) << endl;
cout << "Key is " << iter->first << endl;
cout << "Value is " << iter->second << endl;
```

This program produces the following output:

```
Size before: 0
0
Size after: 1
iter is valid: 1
Key is a
Value is 0
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/KRYIA5)

Answer (score 1):

First, let's have a look at [std::unordered_map::operator[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at):

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, performing an insertion if such key does not already exist.
>   If an insertion is performed, the mapped value is value-initialized (default-constructed for class types, zero-initialized otherwise) and a reference to it is returned.

So in your first line `{'a',0}` is inserted into your map. Now you call [std::unordered_map::insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert):

> Inserts element(s) into the container, **if the container doesn't already contain an element with an equivalent key**.

(Emphasize mine.) So if you call `operator[](c)` before `insert({c,1})`, the call to `insert` has no effect, otherwise it inserts `{c,1}`.